# VALGRIND MALLOC and the quest to find an evil segfault

Tags: c

Below will be my code then the txt of Valgrind. I have no idea why its so long, super sorry. I am really new. Please help me understand why there is no error messages at compile time but the program fails? I know it's a memory leak somewhere but I am at my wits end. What am I supposed to be looking for in the below mess?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

// customer record
typedef char customerName[9];

typedef struct customer {
    customerName name;                  // 1-9 upper case letters
    int lineNumber;                     // line number customer gets on
    int time;                           // arrival time at line
    int numberItems;                    // number of items customer has
} customer;

// [singly linked] queue element
typedef customer *qitem;

typedef struct node {
    qitem data;                         // pointer to actual data
    struct node *next;                  // forward pointer to next item
} node;

// queue definition (singly linked list)
// NOTE:
typedef struct queue {
    node *front;                        // pointer to first node in list ie front of line with cashier
} queue;

// qinit -- initialize/reset queue
void qinit(queue *q)
{
    q->front = NULL;
}

// qempty -- returns 1 if empty or 0 if false
int qempty(queue *q)
{
    return (q->front == NULL);
}

// enqueue -- append element to end of queue
void enqueue(queue *q, qitem data)
{
    node *newnode;
    node *prev;

    newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->next = NULL;
    newnode->data = data;

    // find the back of the queue with only a front pointer
    prev = NULL;
    for (node *cur = q->front;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        prev = cur;

    // append to tail of list
    if (prev != NULL)
        prev->next = newnode;

    // add to end of empty list
    else
        q->front = newnode;

}

// dequeue -- dequeue from the front of the queue
qitem dequeue(queue *q)
{
    node *curnode;
    qitem data;

    do {
        curnode = q->front;

        // bug out if list is empty
        if (curnode == NULL) {
            data = NULL;
            break;
        }

        // get node's data value (e.g. pointer to customer struct)
        data = curnode->data;

        // release the node's storage back to the heap
        free(curnode);
    } while (0);

    return data;
}

// qfront -- peek at front of queue
qitem qfront(queue *q)
{
    node *curnode;
    qitem data;

    curnode = q->front;
    if (curnode != NULL)
        data = curnode->data;
    else
        data = NULL;

    return data;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int testCases = 0;
    scanf("%d", &testCases);

    if(testCases > 0 && testCases <= 25){//shortcircuiting???

    while (testCases--){

        queue *q;
        q = malloc(sizeof(queue));
        qinit(q);// starting new queue

        int numCustomers;
        scanf("%d", &numCustomers);

        if(numCustomers < 0 || numCustomers > 11){
            return 0;
        }

        queue* customerArray = (queue*) malloc(sizeof(queue) * 12);

        for ( int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++){

            customer* newCustomer = (customer*) malloc(sizeof(customer));

            scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->time));
            scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->lineNumber));
            scanf("%s", newCustomer->name);
            scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->numberItems));
            enqueue(&customerArray[newCustomer->lineNumber - 1], newCustomer);
        }


        int totalTime = INT_MAX;

        for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
        customer* frontCustomer = qfront(&customerArray[i]);
         if(totalTime < frontCustomer->time)
            {
                totalTime = frontCustomer->time;
            }
            free(frontCustomer);
         }

       while(numCustomers--) {

           int customerToCheckOutLine = 0; int minNumberOfItems = INT_MAX;

        for( int j=11 ; j>=0; j--){

            customer* frontCustomer = qfront(&customerArray[j]);
            if(frontCustomer->time <= totalTime)
            {
                if(frontCustomer->numberItems < minNumberOfItems)
                {
                    customerToCheckOutLine = frontCustomer->lineNumber;
                    minNumberOfItems = frontCustomer->numberItems;
                }
                free(frontCustomer);
            }
        }


        customer* customerToCheckOut = qfront(&customerArray[customerToCheckOutLine -1 ]);
        totalTime += 30;
        totalTime += (customerToCheckOut->numberItems) * 5;
           dequeue(&customerArray[customerToCheckOutLine - 1]);
       }
        free(customerArray);

    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

sample in

2
5
10 1 STEVEN 12
12 6 AHMAD 8
13 1 JENNY 40
22 6 JERMAINE 39
100000 12 AMALIA 53
6
100 1 A 100
200 2 B 99
300 3 C 98
400 4 D 97
500 5 E 96
600 6 F 95

Comment: I tried to add the Valgrind /out but it was so long that it didn't show up. I am not sure why the output was so complicated nearly 30 pages like 90,000 characters. Not because of all the leaks just random text. 40 loss entries that all said maybe memory loss.

Comment: `typedef char customerName[9];` seems unreasonably short for a name, escpecially as you don't restrict the input in `scanf("%s", newCustomer->name);` and `customerName name;`

Comment: thanks. That was a requirement in the assignment. Names will be that length only. thank you though because that will cause a buffer overflow? I would I restrict it at input?

Comment: What do imagine will happen when you enter a name such a `ABCDEFGHI` (9 or more characters)? You need `scanf("%8s", newCustomer->name);` but then you omit to check the return value from the *other* `scanf` statements, to see if they were successful. I mean the next line should be `if(scanf("%d", &(newCustomer->numberItems)) != 1) {/*handle error*/}`

Comment: this is my second program. thank you. I need it to run. :(

Comment: Another way you can do it is to enter the name into a much longer string, say `char temps[256]` and truncate it yourself with `temps[8] = 0` before making a `strcpy` into `newCustomer->name`.

Comment: is this the source of the memory leak or just SA?

Comment: Not directly. If you overflow a buffer anything might happen.

Comment: can you tell me where the memory leak is? I can give you the Valgrind out, I don't know how to read it. It is suppose to be a simple thing but nothing in coding seems simple

Comment: Can you post sample input that reproduces the problem? Can you strip down your program into a [mcve]? People will have a much better chance of being able to help if they can compile and run the code for themselves, and if it is not full of unnecessary stuff that doesn't affect the bug.

Comment: Note that memory leaks, although they should be fixed, are usually *not* the cause of segfaults - they do not involve access to invalid memory.  So you may be focusing on the wrong thing.  If valgrind reports invalid reads or writes, focus on those reports - otherwise set valgrind aside for now and use a different tool, such as a debugger, to help understand where the crash is occurring.

Comment: wow I didn't know that. I appended the code with sample in.

Comment: By the way, remarks like "this is due tomorrow" tend to annoy people and are generally counterproductive to getting rapid help; see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest.

Comment: So, you think this is hard. You are correct. This is intentionally hard. This is done with full intention; the only way we can teach the essential skill of debugging, that of _thinking at two levels of abstraction at the same time_ while keeping the code small enough for one person to handle in a short exercise, is to give you a language with no safety rails and a piece of homework that cannot be solved without dynamic memory.

Comment: 'Please help me understand why there is no error messages at compile time but the program fails?'  You should be aware that this behaviour is nomal during development.  That is why testing and debugging are steps in sofware development.  Compared with those steps, writing code that compliles is trivial.

Comment: thanks my professor is laughing quietly somewhere off in the distance. If debugging is so important why I am being left to YouTube and google to learn it? sorry just thinking outloud. thank you

Comment: @help_stuck89 an excellent question, and one you should ask your prof!  There are no non-trivial apps without bugs, and test/debug is a vital exercise to reduce the level of bugs, and so increase the quality, until you can con customers into payi... demonstrate to customers that the software is sufficiently fit for purpose to accept it:)

Comment: IMHO, a good tuition plan should start a) Hello World!   b) adding two numbers.  c) intro to debugging and logging.....

Answer (score 1):

On reaching this line

```
    // release the node's storage back to the heap
    free(curnode);
```

You have a live pointer in the queue pointing to `currnode`. The next time you call a queue function, it's going to deference that pointer. You need to adjust the contents of the queue in `dequeue()`.

Comment: Apologies, what do you mean live pointer? I don't know any lingo or anything. How does my dequeue function dereference a pointer when I call queue?

Comment: @help_stuck89: Dereference is here: `curnode = q->front;`. So what actually happens the second time dequeue runs.

Answer (score 1):

I found two bugs:

```
    queue* customerArray = (queue*) malloc(sizeof(queue) * 12);

    for ( int i = 0; i < numCustomers; i++){
        // ...
        enqueue(&customerArray[newCustomer->lineNumber - 1], newCustomer);
    }
```

The queues in `customerArray` are never initialized, so their `front` pointers may contain garbage, causing `enqueue` to crash.

```
    customer* frontCustomer = qfront(&customerArray[i]);
     if(totalTime < frontCustomer->time)
        {
            totalTime = frontCustomer->time;
        }
        free(frontCustomer);
     }
```

`frontCustomer` may be null if there were no elements in a particular queue.  If this happens, `frontCustomer->time` will dereference a null pointer and crash.

Comment: So I suppose when I intialized q at the top of main that did nothing? I can just qinit(customerArray); to initialize?

Comment: @help_stuck89: `qinit(q)` only initialized the queue pointed to by `q` (which doesn't actually appear to be used at all) and had no effect on the 12 additional queues in `customerArray` (which didn't even exist yet).  If you just call `qinit(customerArray)` it will only initialize the first of the 12; it's equivalent to `qinit(&customerArray[0])`.  To initialize all 12 of them you will need to have a loop.

Comment: oh thank you. I noticed the first part right away but the rest there is very helpful. I did not understand that qinit(customerArray) will only do one.

Comment: I placed the qinit call inside my for loop that was already taking input for each customerArray

Comment: do you mean if the queue is uninitialized or that inside of the array and empty position in the queue could make it crash? If so, I think I need to handle the exception by another if statement? I don't know how to make it pretty yet.